# Why are inline-block divs inside button becoming centered?

Tags: html, css, button, centering

Trying to make a nice meaningful button I noticed following:
When having inline-block divs inside a button they become centered without us programmers/stylers having any control over it...

I would like them to have a certain distance from the left or right border of the button.

HTML

```
<button>
    <div class="button-inner button-inner-left">Left</div>
    <div class="button-inner button-inner-right">Right</div>
</button>
```

CSS

```
button {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
}
.button-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.button-inner-left {
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.button-inner-right {
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Here's a codepen for it:

https://codepen.io/JhonnyJason/pen/PRZNpN

- How comes that?
- Why is that?

Basicly I have 2 Solutions to this problem:

- using flexbox https://codepen.io/JhonnyJason/pen/WzrxVB
- making button position: relative; and the .button-inner's position: absolute; and then brutally force them to the coordinates they belong to.
  https://codepen.io/JhonnyJason/pen/EEPyqN

PS: Soo next time when I encounter the problem of not being able to center something I will introduce a wrapper button xD

Comment: Why do you put divs inside a button?

Comment: You should inspect your button element.  "Button" has styling out of the box.  If you want to override it with your own styling, try using "!important" for your class or id

Comment: By default, the `user-agent` sets the button's `text-align` to `center` in most browsers. `inline-block` elements respect that and will be centered.

Comment: It happens because buttons, by default have `text-align: center` in most browsers. Another option is to set a width of `50%` on each `.button-inner`, and use `float: right` on `.button-inner-right`.

Comment: @user7396598 There really is no need to recommend the use of `!important` there. Overriding user agent styles doesn't require `!important`. [`!important` is evil...](https://j11y.io/css/dont-use-important/)

Comment: @BenM If it isn't required then don't use it.  There is nothing evil about overriding styling you do not want.  I failed to notice that he was not attempting to override the style directly on the button, only in his div at the moment.

Comment: @user7396598 No, there is nothing evil about overriding styles. But if you need to do that, add specificity to your selectors, don't use `!important`. You'll quickly find that your code is unmaintainable.

Comment: @Alessandro.Vegna I use divs inside a button to achieve a styling I would not achieve otherwise.
Probable a good question is there why then use Button anyways - for the sole reason that a screen reader knows that it's a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens cause by default, all buttons has `text-align: center`, if you force the button to have `text-align: left` it will go all to left

It is to notice that the text-align property does influence the alignment of the inline-blocks.

Comment: Wow yhea, did not think of that the button itself already has a text-align property which will opinionate the alignment of the whole div...

Answer (score 1):

It is centered because every browser apply it's own default CSS:

Open the developer tool and see the applied classes on button:

Chrome says: "user agent stylesheet"

```
input[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i], input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    color: buttontext;
    background-color: buttonface;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2px 6px 3px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: buttonface;
    border-image: initial;
}
```

Solution is not difficult, you already know that.

Answer (score 0):

this should work if i understand the question correctly
first get rid of button-inner-left and right classes, you dont need them. for button just change the display to flex like you did on one of the codepens and add 'justify-content: center' and 'align-content: center' then change the margin to on button-inner to 'margin: 0 auto' classes like so:

```
.button{
  padding 0
  margin 0
  display flex
  width 50vw
  height 5vw
  justify-content center
  align-content center
}

  .button-inner{
    text-align center
    margin 0 auto}
```